# Disable Maven dependency resolution hint in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

How can I get rid of that annoying Netbeans hint *"Search Dependency at Maven Repositories for Foo"*? It's given to me all the time even when it makes completely no sense like on missing fields (screen attached) and pushes down better hints.

I already disabled **Editor -> Hints -> Maven -> Resolve Missing Class Dependency** but that did not help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like bug. Please file an issue at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/

BTW: the "better hints" will have higher priority in the next release (already integrated in the dev builds) - https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231133